# HTTP Response Code 0 - Site is working

Tags: php, html, httpresponse

I am making a website that will check if a website is working and live. I pass in the URL of the site I would like to check and the following code will check if the site is live and return the HTTP response code as well as true or false.

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)
{
    if($url == NULL) return false;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($httpcode == 0) {
        return array (false, $httpcode);
    }
    else if($httpcode < 400){
        return array (true, $httpcode);
    } else {
        return array (false, $httpcode);
    }
}
```

With one of the sites I am testing though I am getting the HTTP response code of 0 even though I know that the site is live and working.

The site is very slow as its a large site on a not very powerful server so response times can vary between 7 - 25 seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: since  respnse time of server is 7-25 second and you set your `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` to 5 second thats why you are getting 0 because connection is closed before any response is coming. change it to 300 and check:-   https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html

Comment: @Anant thanks that really helped. I also needed to increase the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 300 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Based on these two links:-***

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html

***And***

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html

*First one is:- `set maximum time the request is allowed to take`*

*Second one is:-  `timeout for the connect phase`*

As you said that the `Site URL` you are hitting is taking 7-25 second for responding. meanwhile your `CURL request` is terminated and closed because of these two time settings.

Increase these two time settings in your code and it will work for you.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I will offer 2 alternatives for you to compare - along with your curl() function, you will have 3 options to see which one is better/faster for you.

**Option A** (all php versions), requires fopen() to be activated:

```
if (!$fp = fopen($url, 'r')) 
{
    trigger_error("Unable to open URL ($url)", E_USER_ERROR);

}
$headers = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
fclose($fp);    
$http_header_info = $headers['wrapper_data'][0];
$httpCode = (int)substr($http_header_info, 9, 3);
```

**Option B** (php5+):

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$http_header_info = $headers[0];
$httpCode = substr($http_header_info, 9, 3);
```

Also, if anyone has benchmarks on these 3 approaches, i am curious to see which is more appropriate (only for retrieving http response headers of course)

Answer (score 0):

Code 0 returns often when used invalid URL syntax or host not found error.

You can also call curl_error($ch) function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to determine error details.